# Replace part of img path with regex in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, image, replace, src

I want to look through the entire page on a site and replace relative img paths with "/". For example:

```
    $("body img").attr("src",function(){
        return this.src.replace("uploads","/uploads");
    });
```

However, in cases where the relative path could be different than whats above, I want to use regex to account for all the different scenarios. I know the images will all reside in the same location, but the various paths to replace could be "uploads, ../uploads, or ../../uploads, etc.

Any help would be appreciated..?

Comment: I believe some browsers report the absolute URL of the image src, instead of what's in the HTML attribute. This will complicate things. Regardless, what's the value of what you're trying to do? Are you changing the actual images?

Comment: ...or simplify things. You could check first up if the URL is already absolute, and then set the attribute explicitly to that. Or I suppose for all intents and purposes, your work there is done. Of course you still have to handle the case where the browser does NOT do this for you.

Comment: Thats a good point. I did not think of browsers who change links. Im actually requesting this for a cms that automatically changes links as a cleanup mechanism (go figure). So my ultimate goal is to find all paths that are not /uploads/... and change them accordingly. Im not replacing images, just ensuring that once cms editing is complete, the images will still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace(/^/,"/"));
      $('body').append('<br />');
$('body').append($(this).attr('src'));

})​
```

here is fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7yNg7/

Comment: Thanks, but this does not account for "../" or "../../"
How would i account for those with regex as they are more common

Comment: Had to do some minor tweaks but finally got it working the way i needed. 
Just had to change .replace(/^/,"/"));
to .replace(/.*uploads/,"/my/jmg/path"));

Thanks for the help.